# Monitor.Pulse(All) then Monitor.Wait()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Today I've seen a `PulseAll()`/`Wait()` combo like in the code below for the first time.

The code below is a simplified version I just used to verify if the 2 threads would actually run in an alternating fashion (the real code I saw this had the PulseAll/Wait combo in a producer thread and a consumer thread, and there are conditions so that it all makes more sense). And they do always run alternately!

My question: Is this common practice, in cases where 2 threads want to wake up each other alternately? (Well, aside from the fact that Pulse() would probably do as well here)

```cs
int flipflop = 0;
object q = new object();
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock(q)
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref flipflop, 1, 0) != 0)
                throw new Exception("flip");
            Monitor.PulseAll(q);
            Monitor.Wait(q);
        }
    }
}).Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000); // just to make sure above thread starts before below one
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (q)
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref flipflop, 0, 1) != 1)
                throw new Exception("flop");
            Monitor.PulseAll(q);
            Monitor.Wait(q);
        }
    }
}).Start();
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + ": " + Volatile.Read(ref flipflop));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: I would say that it is a bad idea to keep entering/exiting the lock - i.e. do that *outside* the `while`, but otherwise: if it works, etc

Comment: Barrier class, Duffy explains it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/may/clr-inside-out-9-reusable-parallel-data-structures-and-algorithms#S4).

Comment: @MarcGravell Please rephrase / elaborate, I'm not quite sure what you mean.